# Text size does not change in TextView using a style in Android Studio

Tags: android, text, textview, styles, size

I am trying to style some TextViews to have a given text size.  Changing the size in the style does nothing to the TextView, while changing it in the layout XML has the correct effect.  What am I missing?

Style:

```
<style name="SliderTextTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
</style>
```

Layout XML for the TextView:

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_frame"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="5">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/color_wheel"
            android:src="@drawable/color_wheel_730"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/SliderTextTheme"
                android:textColor="@color/RGBW_red"
                android:text="@string/color_red"/>
            <SeekBar
                style="@style/ColorSeekBar"
                android:id="@+id/red_seekbar"
                android:progressTint="@color/RGBW_red"
                android:thumbTint="@color/RGBW_red" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/red_value"
                style="@style/SliderTextTheme"
                android:textColor="@color/RGBW_red"
                tools:text="100" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/SliderTextTheme"
                android:textColor="@color/RGBW_green"
                android:text="@string/color_green"/>
            <SeekBar
                style="@style/ColorSeekBar"
                android:progressTint="@color/RGBW_green"
                android:thumbTint="@color/RGBW_green" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/green_value"
                style="@style/SliderTextTheme"
                android:textColor="@color/RGBW_green"
                tools:text="100" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/SliderTextTheme"
                android:textColor="@color/RGBW_blue"
                android:text="@string/color_blue"/>
            <SeekBar
                style="@style/ColorSeekBar"
                android:progressTint="@color/RGBW_blue"
                android:thumbTint="@color/RGBW_blue" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blue_value"
                style="@style/SliderTextTheme"
                android:textColor="@color/RGBW_blue"
                tools:text="100" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/SliderTextTheme"
                android:textColor="@color/RGBW_white"
                android:text="@string/color_white"/>
            <SeekBar
                style="@style/ColorSeekBar"
                android:progressTint="@color/RGBW_white"
                android:thumbTint="@color/RGBW_white" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/white_value"
                style="@style/SliderTextTheme"
                android:textColor="@color/RGBW_white"
                tools:text="100" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test_button_1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Send Colors"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom. Does the textview show at all when you use the width as 0dp? Can you please post the complete xml layout too

Comment: Are the other properties in the style working for the textview?

Comment: See complete XML.  It seems like some attributes make changes and some do not.  The layout attributes are working, but the text size and style do not.  I cannot change text style (bold, etc) or size through the style.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your style to work and adjust the text size by by changing

```
<item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
```

If you require the 0dp width to work with your weight attribute, check to make sure that the TextView you are manipulating is definitely inside of a LinearLayout.

Comment: This does not make a difference for me, I have added the full XML for the activity, see above.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to use parent = Textview Widget for your style and used android:textSize rather than just the textSize attribute inside your style.